# Select Users who have made the most positive contributions

Tags: mysql, sql

I thought I had this, but it's clear I don't. From the table below, I'm trying to display users who have made the most positive contributions (articles) on top, followed by the ones who didn't. The table is simple, `artc_id` is the article Id, `artc_status` is the status which shows if an article was approved or not. `0` is approved, `1` is not, then comes the user who wrote the article.

**The results I'm trying to achieve are as follows:**

```
Total Contributions Positive    Contributing User
4                   4           2
3                   2           1
1                   1           4
3                   0           3
```

**Table**

```
"id"    "artc_id"   "artc_status"   "artc_user" "artc_country"
"1"     "1"         "0"             "1"         "US"
"2"     "2"         "0"             "1"         "US"
"3"     "3"         "1"             "1"         "US"
"4"     "4"         "0"             "2"         "US"
"5"     "5"         "0"             "2"         "US"
"6"     "6"         "0"             "2"         "US"
"7"     "7"         "0"             "2"         "US"
"8"     "8"         "1"             "3"         "US"
"9"     "9"         "1"             "3"         "US"
"10"    "10"        "1"             "3"         "US"
"11"    "11"        "0"             "4"         "US"
```

**The Sql I came up with**

```
select count(artc_status) as stats , artc_user from contributions where artc_status = 0 group by artc_user order by  stats desc;
```

I'm not having much luck getting results like I posted above. Can you please assist? This is completely beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
     count(artc_status) as stats , 
     count(case when artc_status=1 then 1 end) Positive,      
     artc_user[Contributing User] 
from 
    contributions 
group by 
    artc_user 
order by  stats desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need conditional aggregation to get the two summary columns:

```
select count(*) as TotalContributions, count(artc_status = 0) as PositiveContributions, artc_user
from contributions
group by artc_user
order by PositiveContributions desc;
```

Comment: This is close, but TotalContributions and PositiveContributions are the same. Not like how I posted, and I can't seem to figure what to fix to make it work right...